# Subversion update command performance

Tags: performance, svn, svn-update

When I execute a SVN update on a directory, how does svn execute it?  Does it execute update on each file in the directory regardless of file's diff status from the working directory?  Or does it execute update only on the files that are "out of sync"?

Answer (score 0):

`svn update` fetches only the delta between your WC's state and the state of the repository.